# canon printer ts3151 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, canon

I have red so many webpages, writing so many commands into the terminal now that Im quite fed up actually. Nothing works....Regretting installing 20.04 distro. Trying to install Canon printer TS3151 driver. Sorry to say this, but on Windows 10 it took me 5 seconds without reading thru a bunch of webpages. I thaught ubuntu had come further than this.  So my question is: Has anybody the real answer to this??? Had luck with it? How do I do it?

Comment: USB connected, we imagine. Your 5 seconds experience would be feasible if you installed 20.10. If you want to stick with 20.04 for some reason, search for ipp-usb.

Comment: USB connected yes. Ipp-usb is already installed. Thanx for the words Brian. They didn't solve the problem, but nobody else has come with solutions either. I will look into it

Comment: Linux have been around since 2004 and I have problems installing a printer! Wow

Comment: Switch the printer off. Leave for a minute. Switch on. Give `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7` and `systemctl list-units "ipp-usb*" | grep service`.

Comment: I got it to work. Answers to the comands Brian: "Couldn't open device, some information will be missing" made me sucpisious of the USB connection, so went behind the wall and changed the cable and the USB port. Then pong :) Added the printer which now shows up correctly. That i saw both the TS series printer (named TS3100_series) and the generic CUPS was ready in the settings, misled me. Now the correct one shows up as third option (Canon-3100-series) Than you Brian !:)